# Certreq -retrieve can't find the specified CA

Tags: powershell, certificate, certificate-authority

I'm currently writing a Powershell script and have run into a bit of a roadblock.  Basically, the script requests, approves, and retrieves new certificates from our CA using certreq.exe and certutil.exe.

So far, I have the request and approval working fine, but as soon as I try to retrieve the newly-approved cert I get a 'directory name is invalid' referring to the CA.  I'm using the exact same -config string for all the other commands, but it fails on the certreq.exe -retrieve call.  If I remove it, it prompts me to select the correct CA out of a list, of which there is only the one.  I'd very much like to avoid that, as I'm trying to automate the renewal of 450+ certificates and having to sit here and click a button for each one will somewhat defeat the whole point.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

---

More info:

Powershell script flows as such:

1. Create .inf file
2. Run certreq.exe -new using the generated inf file to create a .req
3. Run certreq.exe -submit with the generated .req
4. The RequestID is captured from the -submit command and passed to certutil.exe -Resubmit to approve it
5. Run certreq -retrieve with the captured RequestID, fails saying it cannot find the CA that was used in both the certreq -submit and certutil -resubmit commands.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in PowerShell scripts:

```
invoke-expression -command "certreq -config `"$OnlineCA`" -Retrieve $RequestId `"$CertificateFileName`" "
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `-config` parameter. Please check out the TechNet page for more details on the options included in `certreq.exe` and `certutil.exe`.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296456.aspx

I know I am too late to answer this, but hopefully this will help someone else.